# Limit of fractional part

Tags: limits

Prove that the limit as n tends to infinity from
$\{n!\sqrt2\}$ does not exist.
where {} denotes fractional part and "!" denotes factorial.

I don't have many ideas. I would try to show that , given an arbitrary term $x_n$ we can find another term $x_m$, m>n such that $|x_n-x_m|>a$ where $a$ is some fixed number. And so the sequence cannot converge.

Comment: Could you please show what you have tried?

Comment: I suspect that if $\{n!\alpha\}$ converges, then $\alpha$ is rational or transcendental. Note that the convergence gives us some nice rational approximations for $\alpha$ - but perhaps not nice enough to prove my supicion

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen while the conjecture sounds sound, I'm not sure I agree with your remark that the rational approx. are good: even for $\exp(1)$ which has one of the most 'natural' representation for this problem, its approx. is $\sum \limits_{i=1}^N \frac{1}{i!}$, a fraction with denominator $N!$, and the error is $O\big(\frac{1}{N!}\big)$. That does not even reach the Liouville measure of $e$ which is $2$ (we'd need an error around $\frac{1}{(N!)^2}$. So I don't think we could find an absurdity using that $\sqrt{2}$ has Liouville measure $2$ (maybe you meant 'nice approx' in a specific sense)